# How to include a yml file in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I created a yml file called oauth.yml file. i want it to include it in the rails application. Where should i include it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should possibly include it under the config folder:

```
app/config/oauth.yml
```

Let's imagine your file is like this:

```
development:
  key: some_key
  secret: some_secret
test:
  key: some_key
  secret: some_secret
```

Now, somewhere in your rails app, possibly in an initializer file (under app/config/initializers) you'll load this file to a variable or class:

```
all_oauth_config = YAML.load_file( File.join( Rails.root, 'app', 'config', 'oauth.yml' ) )
current_oauth_config = all_oauth_config[Rails.env] 
#now do something with this current_oauth_config variable
```

Comment: I should define somewhere in the application that i have oauth.yml file otherwise how do rails know that it should load oauth.yml file

Comment: Rails will never know, you're the one supposed to load it.